# javascript variable substitution for this.refresh , window.refresh

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, cordova

In my phone-gap index.html javascript part, window.refresh is to be used for IOS and this.refresh for android. I want to use the same index.html for both. Through (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(), i can distinguish between IOS and android, but i don't want to apply this condition every time window. or this. is to be used. Can i apply this condition globally and assign value to a variable viz. 'this' for android and 'window' for IOS and then use that variable wherever required. Is this kind of a thing possible or any workaround so that multiple if -else statements can be avoided.

Any suggestions are most welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try if `this.refresh` exists and call it. If its undefined you can fallback to `window.refresh`. Code example:

```
if(this.refresh === undefined) {
    window.refresh();
} else {
    this.refresh();
}
```

I'm not sure which way it would make the most sense, but I hope you get the concept: if something is `undefined`, you can't call it and need to figure out something else.

Comment: no actually my question was i dont want to apply these if-else conditions everywhere i am using this. or window.. Just once globally if i apply this condition once and keep on using some variable instead of this or window.

Answer (score 0):

extending jsalonen answer

```
<script>
function browserRefresh()
{
   if(this.refresh === undefined) {
        window.refresh();
    } else {
        this.refresh();
    } 
}
</script>
```

and when ever you want to refresh just call

```
browserRefresh();
```

Comment: Actually i found the answer, i was thinking to access global variables we have to use this.var for android and window.var for IOS. But no, turns out that only var is enough no prefix(this. , window.) is required for both the platforms.